# OnPropertyChanged sometimes does not update UI in ListView, only after scroll or another activity

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i have a problem, when i work with list items, listview does not redraw them if they area of visibility, reflected only after I've scrolled the element out of view and back, or I've tap on item, it appeared after the updated to Xamarin v4, when i used Xamarin v3 everything was good

bug in this video https://youtu.be/u-a1cWKywKI

Model.cs

```
 bool _CheckBoxIsVisible = false;
            public bool CheckBoxIsVisible
            {
                get
                {
                    return _CheckBoxIsVisible;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_CheckBoxIsVisible != value)
                    {
                        _CheckBoxIsVisible = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("CheckBoxIsVisible");
                    }
                }
            }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            {
                if (PropertyChanged == null)
                    return;

                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            #endregion
```

container.xaml

```
<controls:CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,5,0" Type="Check" IsVisible="{Binding CheckBoxIsVisible}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelect}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

container.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<MailModel> Items = new ObservableCollection<MailModel>();
    MailItemsListView.ItemsSource = Items;


foreach (var item in Items)
                    {
                        item.CheckBoxIsVisible= true;
                    }
```

Comment: If you are sure its an issue why not log it with the Xamarin.Forms team on [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues)

Comment: yes,someone described it was 21 hours ago, but how can I fix it [github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6830)

Comment: @Artur, I can reproduce this issue at my side, and I have reported this issue for MS support, please wait a minute, and see update in github.

Answer (score 0):

try to change value of property on main thread and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Change xaml code like below

```
<controls:CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,5,0" Type="Check" IsVisible="{Binding CheckBoxIsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelect}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Note:-

> IsVisible="{Binding CheckBoxIsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"